# Authentication in user Java with MySQL

Tags: java

I have to make an application after a login, take you to a window with a few options, which change according to the type of user you been logged (administrator, manager, normal user), I've created the login dialog and connected to the database, but do not know how to do that: 1.Java distinguish a user is admin, manager or normal. 2.You take a different window by type .. If you could help me would be very grateful, as I'm quite lost ... Thank you!

Comment: Is this a web application? If so, are you using any frameworks?  Or is this a swing application?

Comment: is this a web application? swing? or?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, as you don't tell the application base (if web application, desktop application, used framework etc) then I will need to be very simple in my answer.

- Install your database
- Install your logintable and your data (e.g. admin / adminpwd; user / userpwd etc)

If Swing:

- Create a login-window that asks for username and password
- If admin then load admin-frame, if user load user-frame otherwise show error.

If Web application:

- Create a simple login html form, asking for username and password
- Do a user check in your Jsp/Servlet, put user-info in session and redirect to user-page if user, to admin-page if admin, otherwise error-page (you could make a simple check in pages to verify that user-info exists in session, in case of...)

This is a very very basic flow, you could of course make a group/role table/column that connects each user to a group. Which makes it easier when you have plenty of users.
There are many frameworks out there that makes this easier, but the basics are the same! ;)

Comment: is a desktop software that I'm developing for college, and I have the database tables with users, roles and permissions in mysql.
login I have also connected to the database with users table detail is not like the other tables apply roles and permissions. in short, what I need is to have multiple profiles.

Comment: administered by entering the JFrame buttons have activated (see delete modify and save)
if you enter the security guard activated only has the consulting and save JFrame
if it enters the auxiliary has consulted button JFrame

Comment: java as I can apply roles?
as I can disable the buttons depending on the user?
as they apply in my code the login?